# Angular not showing static HTML file that is declared in assets

Tags: angular

I would like to show a static HTML file as part of the Angular app, so included it in `assets` section in `angular.json` file. But still when accessing it http://localhost:4200/msal2.html via the browser, the angular routing tries to resolve it and shows the "Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment..".
I am using Angular v12 on windows.

If I access that static html page as http://localhost:4200/assets/msal2.html, then the response is the html content present in the `index.html` in the angular app, not the content of my static html file.

I have referred similar questions in SO, but **not** finding relevant solutions. [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416871/routing-to-static-html-page-in-angular-6), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485093/angular-routing-doesnt-work-for-assets-defined-in-angular-json).

What am I missing?  is it only possible by `creating` a `component` that can show this static html content, as shown in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796441/14973743)?

The below is the `assets` section in the angular.json file,

```
        "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/static/msal2.html"
            ],
```

Comment: When you run `ng build`, where exactly is the `msal2.html` file placed?

Comment: after I build, msal2.html is in `dist/<projectname>/assets/static` folder.

Comment: Can you not just put it in the root instead of in the assets folder..?

Comment: Then you need to access the file via URL `http://localhost:4200/assets/static/msal2.html`. Alternatively you can specify your asset as object, giving you further config options, see [docs](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#asset-config)

Comment: Already tried accessing that path, doesn't work - response is html content from index.html, anything to do with defining `base` path or any addition to the `route` configuration to be done?